# How to move view when editText is focused and keyboard is open?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-view, android-softkeyboard

I have a ScrollView

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".LoginActivity">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/login_form"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_margin="55dp"
            android:src="@drawable/sss" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="@font/helvetica_neue_cyr_roman"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:text="@string/title_email"
            android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:errorEnabled="true"
            app:errorTextAppearance="@style/ErrorText"
            app:hintEnabled="false"
            app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"
            app:passwordToggleTint="@color/colorAccent">

            <AutoCompleteTextView
                android:id="@+id/email"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="46dp"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/colorWhite"
                android:fontFamily="@font/helvetica_neue_cyr_medium"
                android:hint="@string/hint_email"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                android:textColorHint="@color/colorHint"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="@font/helvetica_neue_cyr_roman"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:text="@string/title_password"
            android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:errorEnabled="true"
            app:errorTextAppearance="@style/ErrorText"
            app:hintEnabled="false"
            app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"
            app:passwordToggleTint="@color/colorAccent">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/password"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/colorWhite"
                android:fontFamily="@font/helvetica_neue_cyr_medium"
                android:hint="@string/hint_password"
                android:imeActionId="6"
                android:imeActionLabel="@string/action_sign_in"
                android:imeOptions="actionUnspecified"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                android:textColorHint="@color/colorHint"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/sign_in_button"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/button_shape"
            android:fontFamily="@font/helvetica_neue_cyr_medium"
            android:text="@string/action_sign_in"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
            android:textSize="16sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
 </RelativeLayout>
```

And i have some issues with showing what i exactly need.

[This is how view looks by default](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VGhNZ.jpg)
*not scrollable*

[Clicking on email editText](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yFek1.jpg)
*scrollable*

[Password editText click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8wMBl.jpg)
*scrollable*

[And this is the screenshot i want the app to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vo1SG.jpg)

By saying that i mean - i need my view to move upper to the same position if i click on editTexts. And after keyboard disappears i need view to come to default position.

*I dont need to scroll view after keyboard is open.*

**I've been trying to make that happen with adding**

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

**and**

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

**to manifest**

Is it even possible to make?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I believe with the correct layout configuration(maybe just a constrain layout instead of the scroll?), you can hide the logo with `Visibility.GONE` programmatically when one of the fields is clicked and bring the logo back when the field lose focus.